# Is it possible to remove duplicates from a sorted list in less than O(n) time?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I suspect there is a way if you can save by locating the other end of a range of repeated values faster than by iterating through that sublist

Comment: What do you mean by "list"? In a linked list, traversal is unavoidably O(N). If you just mean "some linear data structure", you can use a binary search in a data structure that supports binary or random traversal (e.g., a tree or an array).

Comment: if the sorting algorithm has O(nlogn) time complexity and you can remove the duplicates in O(1) time, the overall complexity will still be O(nlogn).

Comment: To clarify I mean a linear data structure that supports random access, but not a tree.  Lets call it an array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, no. Imagine a list of N duplicates. You would have to make N-1 removals, hence O(N).

If you specify a particular data structure with better than O(1) removal of elements, then there might better way for certain sorts of inputs.

Even if you can efficiently remove a range of elements in O(1), and it takes O(1) time to find a duplicate - imagine a list where there are N/2 pairs of duplicates. You'll still have to do N/2 searches and remove N/2 ranges, both of which are O(N).

(there's also a bit of ambiguity as the question title is 'remove duplicates', but the body is specific to removing one range)

If the list resulting from your sort has the following representation - each node has a value, and an occurrence count for that, then removing the duplications for one value will trivially set the count to 1 for that node. ( A [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) probably has similar characteristics, assuming a decent garbage collected environment where there's no cost to reclaiming memory), so that would be O(1) for one duplication. If you need to remove *all* duplicates from the list, it would still be O(N).

Comment: Imagine a list of N duplicates. You would have to make N-1 removals, hence O(N) - No, if you know the beginning and the end of the range of duplicates then you have only one removal.

Comment: @Jakub well, the rest could be chopped off in O(1). Freeing it correctly will give O(n).

Comment: @ruslik - define correctly. A simple check for equality of first and last element is a correct one IMHO.

Comment: @Jakub No, I mean the `remove` operation. For N duplicates you can have one single remove if you don't care about freeing the memory.

Comment: @Jakub that's what I was thinking about with a special case data structure, as opposed to a singly linked list. It wouldn't be a normal list, as to find the other end of the block requires traversing; maybe a skip list would get away with it for that one case. But it still won't  help the second case.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham - I see. If it was a linked list that you would have to go through all the elements to get to the end anyway (to check the value of the last element).

Answer (score 3):

In general there is not, because you can always construct a case where you have O(n) (a list with no duplicates). If you start making assumptions on the data however (for instance that there are at most log n distinct elements), you may get something better (I'm not sure in this particular case though).

This does of course assume that you have some way of doing efficient "bulk removes", meaning that you can remove any range of equal elements in O(1), regardless of its size.

Answer (score 1):

There cant be

as for comparing all the elements with the other we need to do n*(n-1) = n2-n comparisions...`

Answer (score -2):

I would go for a 'binary search' approach for finding ends of ranges:

Let's assume we have a sorted list of n elements.

1. Compare 1-st and n-th element - if equal that whole list is a duplicate.
2. Select a middle element (n/2)
3. Execute search recursively for two sub-lists.

Comment: Are you talking about a linked list or a sorted array?

Comment: How are not going to do O(N) operations if the list is N/2 lots of duplicates?

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev - does it matter?

Comment: @Pete Kirkham - I'm not saying that my algo is always better then O(n). It may be better for certain data sets

Comment: Binary search cannot be really implemented on a linked list because you don't have random access to its elements. How would you "Select a middle element" in O(1)?

Comment: @Jakub that's what I'm trying to say: there are algoritms that for some input will perform in less than O(n). But I cannot imagine one with less than O(n) for the worst case for how the problem is specified.

Comment: @Blagovest there's lists and there's lists. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list is a sorted list, but supports O(lnN) search. For this case, you'd arrange it that the up node's right node's down node is the next value, so removing one range would be O(1).

Comment: Even with a random access list where I can do a binary search, I might have to do that search n times giving me a O(n lg n) time.  I am convinced that O(n) is the lower bound given the possibilities of all dupes or no dupes.