# how do i remove duplicate elements in ArrayList in O(logn) time

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

I have strings as elements in the arraylist and i would like to remove them in O(logn) time, using Java

i have tried using `HashSet` to copy and clear and copy back to another arraylist, but i think that's in O(n) time.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149440

Comment: I'm guessing you will need to look at each element at least once, setting a lower bound of O(n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, even if you have the array sorted it will take `O(n)`. I think you cannot avoid checking each element at least once, so it is impossible to have complexity less than `O(n)`.

Comment: If the array is sorted, then it is possible find a particular element in O(log n).

Comment: @Daniel Sure, but it is impossible to remove duplicates.

Comment: Ah true. I missed that part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings in your array are in sorted order, you can access them in O(log n) time using binary search; however, if they are unsorted, you will need to check each element of the array, giving a lower bound of O(n).

EDIT:
If you are trying to remove duplicates from an already created ArrayList, you must look at each element, which will take O(n) time.  If you are willing to sacrifice on adding, you can add them to the array in sorted order, and then you will never have to remove duplicates because if an element is already there, then you just don't add it; but adding will run in linear time rather than constant time.